# Allocate or Limit resource for pods in Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, cgroups

The resource limit of Pod has been set as:

```
resource
  limit
    cpu: 500m
    memory: 5Gi
```

and there's `10G` mem left on the node.

I've created `5` pods in a short time successfully, and the node maybe still have some mem left, e.g. `8G`.

The mem usage is growing as the time goes on, and reach the limit (`5G x 5 = 25G > 10G`), then the node will be out of response.

In order to ensure the usability, is there a way to set the resource limit on the node?

### Update

The core problem is that pod memory usage does not always equal to the limit, especially in the time when it just starts. So there can be unlimited pods created as soon as possible, then make all nodes full load. That's not good. There might be something to allocate resources rather than setting the limit.

### Update 2

I've tested again for the limits and resources:

```
resources:
  limits:
    cpu: 500m
    memory: 5Gi
  requests:
    cpu: 500m
    memory: 5Gi
```

The total mem is 15G and left 14G, but 3 pods are scheduled and running successfully:

```
> free -mh
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        1.1G        8.3G        3.4M        6.2G         14G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B

> docker stats

CONTAINER           CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O
44eaa3e2d68c        0.63%               1.939 GB / 5.369 GB   36.11%              0 B / 0 B           47.84 MB / 0 B
87099000037c        0.58%               2.187 GB / 5.369 GB   40.74%              0 B / 0 B           48.01 MB / 0 B
d5954ab37642        0.58%               1.936 GB / 5.369 GB   36.07%              0 B / 0 B           47.81 MB / 0 B
```

It seems that the node will be crushed soon XD

### Update 3

Now I change the resources limits, request `5G` and limit `8G`:

```
resources:
  limits:
    cpu: 500m
    memory: 5Gi
  requests:
    cpu: 500m
    memory: 8Gi
```

The results are:
[image]

According to the [k8s source code about the resource check](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/8c60068b368f8ec1cd21fdf25d44c7b165aa9d27/plugin/pkg/scheduler/algorithm/predicates/predicates.go#L393):

[image]

The total memory is only `15G`, and all the pods needs `24G`, so all the pods may be killed. (my single one container will cost more than `16G` usually if not limited.)

It means that you'd better keep the `requests` **exactly equals** to the `limits` in order to avoid pod killed or node crush. As if the `requests` value is not specified, it will be [set to the `limit` as default](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/compute-resources.html), so what exactly `requests` used for? I think only `limits` is totally enough, or IMO, on the contrary of what K8s claimed, I rather like to **set the resource request greater than the limit**, in order to ensure the usability of nodes.

### Update 4

Kubernetes [1.1 schedule the pods mem requests](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/1ef28633870d66fba6883bf1d667dbcfd83f200b/plugin/pkg/scheduler/algorithm/predicates/predicates.go#L120) via the formula:

`(capacity - memoryRequested) >= podRequest.memory`

It seems that kubernetes is not caring about memory usage as [Vishnu Kannan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5289649/vishnu-kannan) said.  So the node will be crushed if the mem used much by other apps.

Fortunately, from the commit [e64fe822](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/commit/e64fe82245303f08f32b0fb9a2fa9efe4a08f91f), the formula has been changed as:

`(allocatable - memoryRequested) >= podRequest.memory`

waiting for the k8s v1.2!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Kubernetes resource specifications have two fields, `request` and `limit`.

`limits` place a cap on how much of a resource a container can use. For memory, if a container goes above its limits, it will be OOM killed. For CPU, its usage may be throttled.

`requests` are different in that they ensure the node that the pod is put on has at least that much capacity available for it. If you want to make sure that your pods will be able to grow to a particular size without the node running out of resources, specify a request of that size. This will limit how many pods you can schedule, though -- a 10G node will only be able to fit 2 pods with a 5G memory request.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean `10G` is teh left mem? I've tested again, my total mem is 15G, and left 14G, then there `5Gi` pods are scheduled and running succefully, other pods are pending. Is it possible the k8s does not count the used mem?

Comment: I'd expect three 5GB pods to be scheduled if your total memory is 15GB, then the rest to be left pending, because there wouldn't be enough unreserved memory to satisfy the requests of the already scheduled pods. You could schedule more pods that don't request a specific amount of memory, and they'll be able to use the memory that's been reserved but isn't yet being used.

Comment: The k8s [source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/plugin/pkg/scheduler/algorithm/predicates/predicates.go#L393) shows exactly what you said. Does it mean, if there's only 1G mem left on a node whose total mem is 15G, it's still possible to create three 5GB pods? If that true, all nodes will be crushed like mine, please check details in the "update 2" of this question. Thanks!

Comment: It might be possible to create them, but only if the memory on the node isn't reserved for the pods that are already there. If all the memory on the node gets used up by the pods there, one or more of them may be killed, as Vishnu describes in his answer.

Comment: With respect, bother you again :) in the situation described on "Update 3", will the three pods be killed soon? OK, would you like to show me some links of documentation, since the resource limitation is critical in my project, it means usability to me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Looks like you already found it in update 4 :) Best of luck with your project!

Answer (score 9):

Kubernetes supports Quality of Service. If your Pods have `limits` set, they belong to the `Guaranteed` class and the likelihood of them getting killed due to system memory pressure is extremely low. If the docker daemon or some other daemon you run on the node consumes a lot of memory, that's when there is a possibility for Guaranteed Pods to get killed.

The Kube scheduler does take into account memory capacity and memory allocated while scheduling. For instance, you cannot schedule more than two pods each requesting 5 GB on a 10GB node.

Memory usage is not consumed by Kubernetes as of now for the purposes of scheduling.

Comment: Thanks! IMO, the 'available mem' should be counted by `totalMem - usedMem - RequestMemByScheduledPod`, and if it is greater than the pod request, the pod should be scheduled, but [k8s source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/plugin/pkg/scheduler/algorithm/predicates/predicates.go#L393) seems different.